# 'Card' does not name a type

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Ubuntu 16.04. Qt5.6

```
#ifndef ACTION_USER_H
#define ACTION_USER_H

#include <headers.h>

class Action_user : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Action_user(QObject *parent = 0);
private:
  Card card1();
};
#endif // ACTION_USER_H
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
    /action_user.h:20: error: 'Card' does not name a type
       Card card1();
       ^
```

Далее:

```
#ifndef CARGO_H
#define CARGO_H
#include <headers.h>

class Card: public QObject  // информация о представителе
{
public:
    QString firstName;  // имя
    QString lastName;   // фамилия
    QString middleName; // отчество
    QString email;
    QString phone;
};

#endif // CARGO_H

#ifndef HEADERS_H
#define HEADERS_H

#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include "action_user.h"
#include "cargo.h"

#endif // HEADERS_H

// cargo.cpp
#include "cargo.h"

Cargo::Cargo(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}
```

Comment: ну так логически напрашивается, что в файл actionuser.h нужно добавить #include "cargo.h" пере объявлением класса Action_user. Как вариант: в файле headers.h подключение заголовков action_user.h и cargo.h поменять местами

Comment: делал оба варианта, результат тот же

Comment: Еще вот это странная конструкция: private:  Card card1(); Нужно без скобок: private:  Card card1;

Comment: Результат аналогичен.

Comment: Забавно, что у вас одни включения в угловых скобках, другие в кавычках. Впрочем, это так, легкая несогласованность, не более того. Интересные у вас также взаимозависимости - циклические (`cargo` включает `headers`, который включает  `cargo` - это точно так надо? :)) И еще - собственно, а что вы включаете в .cpp-файле, который компилируете? И еще - с Qt не работал, так что просто не знаю, что делает макрос `Q_OBJECT` в `class Action_user : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT`

Comment: @Александр Почему? объявление приватной функции-члена, всего-навсего...

Comment: @Harry сделал чтобы небыло циклической ссылки, результат не изменился. Макрос нужен для работы системы сигналов и слотов. Содержимое *.cpp выкладываю в тело вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он затупил из-за циклической зависимости. Избавляйтесь в header.h от включения ваших заголовочных файлов, или вообще от header.h. Включайте их там где это необходимо. Например в Cargo я не вижу необходимости подключать что-либо кроме QString... Проблема исчезнет, когда разберетесь с зависимостями.